# Add Contact to Existing Group programatically in iphone

Tags: ios, addressbook, abrecordref

I want to add ABRecordRef to existing Group. Some how its not working. Here is my code:

```
-(void)addUsers:(NSMutableArray*)users toGroupID:(ABRecordID)groupID {

    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreate();

   // Get Group 
    ABRecordRef group = ABAddressBookGetGroupWithRecordID(addressBookRef,groupID);

    for (User *user in users) {

        int recordId = user.uniqID;

        ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBookRef,(ABRecordID)recordId);

        //add the new person to the record
        ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBookRef, person, nil); 
        ABAddressBookSave(addressBookRef, &error);

        // add the group   
        ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBookRef, group, &error); 
        ABAddressBookSave(addressBookRef, &error);

        // add the person to the group 
        ABGroupAddMember(group, person, &error);         
        ABAddressBookSave(addressBookRef, &error);

        //save the record
        ABAddressBookSave(addressBookRef, nil);

        if (!isMemberAdded) {
            [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Alert" andMessage:@"Some Error Occured While Adding User to Existing Group"];
        }
    }
    BOOL isMembersAddedToGroup = ABAddressBookSave(addressBookRef, nil); 
    if (isMembersAddedToGroup) {
        [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Alert" andMessage:@"Selected Members Added to Existing Group Successfully"];
    }
    else{
        [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Alert" andMessage:@"Some Error Occured While Adding User to Existing Group"];
    }
    CFRelease(addressBookRef);
}
```

Whenever I use above code & try to save it in existing group I get following message in console

```
CPSqliteStatementPerform: constraint failed for INSERT INTO ABGroupMembers (group_id, member_type, member_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
CPSqliteStatementReset: columns group_id, member_type, member_id are not unique for INSERT INTO ABGroupMembers (group_id, member_type, member_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

I am not getting what I am missing in above code. 
Any knid of help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: offtopic: for future projects you can use ABContactHelper from Erica to get a nice contact interface: https://github.com/erica/ABContactHelper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we see the message:

```
CPSqliteStatementPerform: constraint failed for INSERT INTO ABGroupMembers (group_id, member_type, member_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
CPSqliteStatementReset: columns group_id, member_type, member_id are not unique for INSERT INTO ABGroupMembers (group_id, member_type, member_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

Also in [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) :

> The ABAddressBook opaque type (whose instances are known as address
>   books) provides a programming interface to the Address Book—a
>   centralized database used by multiple applications to store personal
>   information about people

(So, internally, this error is caused due to incorrect sqlite query.)

It indicates that there is some issue with `ABGroupAddMember` or `ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBookRef, group, &error);` call.

The problem can be: We have group and person references already with us when we call`ABAddressBookGetGroupWithRecordID` and `ABAddressBookGetGroupWithRecordID` functions.

Now, when `ABAddressBookAddRecord` is executed for both( `person` and `group`) it is adding them to `addressbook` but **not updating their UniqueIds**(`id for person and group ref.`) so  at the time of `ABGroupAddMember` function call it has `person` and `group` with same ids which are added in  `ABGroupMembers` table.

Please, try to print `recordId` for `person` and `group` after you add them to address book(and before you add them to group). if `recordsIds` are not updated then that is the cause, and you will need to fetch `record` for new `recordId`. Also check whether the new `person` and `group` are being added to addresbook or not.

*Currently, I do not mac access to verify my suggestion/answer.

Comment: Thanks for info. I got my error. Actually I am sending wrong group in fucntion.